# How to exclude external library documentation with sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, nox

I am using the generated modules.rst file that appears in the autosummary templates from installing sphinx. When I try to build my sphinx page, I notice that several functions from libraries that I have used also get documented under my own functions. How can I prevent these other functions from appearing?

I have tried adding an `:exclude:` tag under the `Modules` block, but it didn’t change anything.